# Coded constrains not applied on sub view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I struggle with constrains in Xamarin.iOS.

I created a little test application which should only add a green `UIView`  to my main view and position it by constrains. I can add the green view and it will be displayed but only at the top right corner. Ok that's obvious since I set the `Frame` for the view like `this.greenView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 60, 60);`. I than want to apply the constrains so that the green box is like 15point away from the top, left and right (yes, i want the box the be larger than the initial 60).

Constrains:

`this.View.AddConstraints(new[] {
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.greenView, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 1, 15),
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.greenView, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, 1, 15),
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.greenView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 15)
            });`

When I run the application the green box is still at the top right corner and is 60x60 large.

Do any of you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thx in advance for your help.

Full Code:

```
    using CoreGraphics;
    using System;

    using UIKit;

    namespace iosStackViewCoding
    {
        public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
        {
            UIView greenView = null;

            public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
            {
            }

            public override void ViewDidLoad()
            {
                // add sub views
                this.AddGreenBox();

                base.ViewDidLoad();
                // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            }

            public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
            {
                base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
                // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
            }

            public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
            {
                // Layout the view if needed.
                this.View.LayoutIfNeeded();

                // apply initial size and position
                this.greenView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 60, 60);

                // add constrains.
                this.View.AddConstraints(new[] {
                    NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.greenView, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 1, 15),
                    NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.greenView, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, 1, 15),
                    NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.greenView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 15)
                });
            }

            private void AddGreenBox()
            {
                // create view and set background
                greenView = new UIView();
                greenView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;

                // add to main view
                this.View.AddSubview(greenView);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of mistaken in your code

> #### 1. We should not set constraint in `ViewDidLayoutSubviews`!

This method is Called before the UIViewController.View lays out its subviews (which is triggered when the UIKit.UIView.Bounds property is modified) ,in your code `View.AddConstraints` is called every time , means it creates duplicate constraints all time.

> #### 2. We should set `subview.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false before we set constraints on it.

[TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints definition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco)

> #### 3.Constraints  must be sufficient to determine the position and size .

However , just setting Leading, Trailing, Top is not sufficient , you should set height or bottom also.

> #### 4 We'd better not mix frame setting and autolayout .

It is enough to  place views with autolayout, it behaves well than frame setting.

### Final Code :

```
private void AddGreenBox()
{
    // create view and set background
    greenView = new UIView();
    greenView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
    this.View.AddSubview(greenView);

    greenView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

    View.AddConstraints(new[] {
        NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.greenView, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 1, 15),
        NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.greenView, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, 1, -15) ,
        NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.greenView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 15),
        NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.greenView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, -15)
    });
}
```

Comment: Thx!!!!!! That solved my problem. By chance you don't have any tips on how to correctly size a `UiStackView`? Because stackView.SizeToFit() doesn't change the anything...